# Reading NAV compressed blobs blobs from outside c#

Tags: c#

I was trying to implement the code at "[Accessing Compressed Blobs from outside NAV](http://devch.wordpress.com/2014/01/21/accessing-compressed-blobs-from-outside-nav-nav2013-revisited/) "

However in VS2012 I keep getting the error that the BlobReaderStream is not implemented.
Unfortunately searching on google did not return any results. It seems people were able to use this code as is, so there must be some .NET lib that I am missing?

What are your thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The author of the post provides the listing for 'BlobReaderStream' on the page you linked to. It's the second code sample on the page. If you include this in your project you may have more success.

Comment: Either I'm going blind or the page changed after I asked there as well... Anyway thanks for the pointer!

Comment: The author edited the page :) I was SERIOUSLY starting do doubt myself :)